# Combining two dataframes based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to combine different dataframes for NBA data. My first dataframe is from a [basketball-reference](https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_poss.html) page and my second dataframe is from a [538 stats page](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-nba-player-ratings/). I've already webscraped them.

I want to combine them so that it is by the player name. One of the dataframes is still bigger than the other. How can I combine the dataframes together? Both have the column id of "Player"

Comment: Have you looked at [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to use pandas .merge().

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
               'value': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                 'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

merged_df  = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='player')
```